# Printing ASCII in table format

Tags: c, loops, ascii, tabular

Looking for any hints that can help me with the format for my code. I need to print the ASCII table in C but I can't get the proper table format because of the procedural nature of C.

Essentially this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

char header[] = "Dec Hex Oct Char |";
char header2[] = "-----------------|";

int main(){

    char i;

    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",header,header,header,header);
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",header2,header2,header2,header2);

    for(i = 0;i<=31;i++){
        printf("%03d %02X %03o       |",i,i,i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My output looks something like this:

Dec Hex Oct Char | Dec Hex Oct Char | Dec Hex Oct Char |

000 00 000

001 00 001

...

031 1F 037

Now I need the rest of the columns to generate the same thing except for ASCII numbers 32-127

I understand why it's not generating the way I want to..but when I try to nest another for loop inside the first one (to print ASCII numbers 32-63), it doesn't compile so well.

Essentially I'm asking if there's a way to run parallel for loops or use another function inside for() so that it can print the rest of the table on the same line before starting the next line.

Comment: One way is just have another two `printf` lines below your current one: `printf("%03d %02X %03o       |",i+32,i+32,i+32);printf("%03d %02X %03o       |",i+64,i+64,i+64);`. Certainly there other ways to do it as well. In fact, you can even put it all into the one `printf`. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: LOL! "I can't get the proper table format because of the procedural nature of C" C is Turing-complete!

Comment: "it doesn't compile so well". If you want help with that then please show that part of the code and the exact compiler error (don't just give up at the first hurdle!).

Comment: Don't blame C for your lack of programming knowledge.

Comment: you could print all 4 columns in one printf() statement, using appropriate offsets from the current loop counter.    However, the posted code would only print the first 124 ascii values and there are 256 ascii values ranging from 0x00 through 0xFF

Comment: To run parallel `for` loops, you could use threads:-) But that would definitively not help.

Comment: @user3629249: Has ASCII been extended lately? Last time I checked it was a 7 bit code...

Answer (score 1):

When printing ASCII, to display non-printable `char`, use an escape sequence.

```
char *CodeToString(char *dest, char ch) {
   if (isprintf((unsigned char) ch) {
     dest[0] = ch;
     dest[1] = 0;
   } else {
     sprintf(dest, "\\x%02X",  (unsigned char) ch);
   }  
   return dest;
}
```

To print multiple columns, use an interior loop. [@Alan Au](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898156/printing-ascii-in-table-format/32899192#comment53625360_32898156)

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) runs for 0 to 127 [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898156/printing-ascii-in-table-format/32899192#comment53625525_32898156)

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++){
  for (j=0; j < 128; j += 32) {  
    char dest[5];
    printf("%3d %02X %03o %4s |",i+j,i+j,i+j,CodeToString(dest, i+j));
  }
  putc('\n', stdout):
}
```